# Are the number of bonus DoS granted by Unnatural Characteristics (half UC value) rounded up or down?

Tags: dark-heresy-2e

> **Unnatural Characteristic (X):**   One or more of the creature’s characteristics is unnaturally enhanced... Successful tests using a
>   characteristic tied to this trait gain a number of bonus degrees of
>   success equal to half the Unnatural Characteristic value.

If the character has Unnatural Agility (1), does he gain +1 DoS on agility-based tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You round up

**ROUNDING AND MULTIPLYING**

> If a fraction is generated when dividing, unless specified otherwise
> round the result up, even if the fraction is less than one-half.

Page 22 of the Core Rulebook

---

A little mathematical insight. Actually there are three types of rounding.

- Round up (also termed as Ceil value) - You round the number to the nearest higher whole number.
  You can express it symbolically as ⌈x⌉
- Round down (also termed as Floor value) - You round the number to the nearest lower number. You can express it symbolically as ⌊x⌋
- Round off - You round it to the nearest whole number. If the digit after the decimal point is equal or greater than 0 and equal or lower than 4, it would be the lower nearest whole number. If the digit after the decimal point is equal or greater than 5 and equal or lower than 9, it would be the higher nearest whole number.

Most of the time unless stated otherwise, rounding is used as a shortened form of "rounding of".